# How to pass a list as parameter function into a timeit call in Python 3.2.3?

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x

```
function_to_test(test, mylist): #test as an int, mylist as a list of int
     do_something    
     return something

function_generates_a_list(min, max): #min, max are int
     do_something
     return a_List
```

I need to timeit the function_to_test and only this one. The purpose is to test code in order to determine which one is the best to test if a int is in a list of int. (`test` is a googolplex and `mylist` is a huge list starting from min to max). Yes, I already know the result of the function, I need to know how many times it will cost.

My problem is: which syntax have I to use with timeit if I want to pass a global list as a local parameter of a function I test?

Comment: Please don't use `list` as a variable name.

Comment: `function_generates_a_list()` has not to be tested. It simply generates the list wich is necessary to `function_to_test` wich has been to be timed.

Comment: I bet that you don't have an `int` that contains a googolplex. That would require, uh, quite a bit of storage.

Comment: @TimPietzcker : understand that i used "int" to speak for an integer, not for the built-in type of a language ... 3/2 is not a integer :)

Comment: OK, then tell me *how* you're storing the googolplex, you've made me curious. (What does 3/2 have to do with all this?)

Comment: I'm not storing anything, I do not need to run the function with googolplex, i only need to test its behaviour in a certain domain to determine wich (could) be its behaviour in the 10^googolplex domain. 3/2 equals 1.5 wich is not a integer. In fact i will trace the response of the time needed by the function on a certain hardware, then transform this response in a mathematical function, then pass wich parameter i want in the matematical function. Then i could guess the time needed by my function to run for 10^10^100 and huge numbers above. Mathematicians doesn't care with pysics you know ?

Comment: @TimPietzcker : in facts, i will stock my hugest test into a 32GB file. And i need to compare the time needed to read the file (and load it into memory) and the time needed to compute the test. If wonder why, it's because I'm about to find an accelerated way to test parity of huge numbers. (works in cryptanalysis) edit : one of the hugest known prime is read in a ~20MB file, could you understand  the matter of my work, uh ? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to create a function that takes no arguments, and calls your function with whatever arguments it needs:

```
mylist = function_generates_a_list()
def newfunc():
   function_to_test(mylist)
```

You can then call `timeit(newfunc)`. You could also do this with a lambda expression - `timeit(lambda: function_to_test(mylist))` is exactly equivalent to the above. If you're using `timeit` module-wise (ie, doing `python -m timeit ...`), you could also do this:

```
python -m timeit --setup='import mymodule' 'mymodule.newfunc()'
```

You could avoid having `newfunc` altogether by having a sufficiently convoluted `setup` string (the call to `function_generates_a_list` has to be in setup, possibly (as here) but not necessarily by happening when you import the module, if you don't want it to be part of your timings), but having the function makes things more flexible and less annoying.

Comment: Uh, not sure i really woke up today :) THX COOP !